# How to stop being diverted to login page after unsuccessful login in Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application which has a mapping:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/users/{username}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getByUsername(username);
    return userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("Username " + username + " is not found."));
}
```

I also have a custom exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    var exception = new ExceptionResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exception, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig is as this:

```
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
             // Many matchers here
             // .....
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("pwd").permitAll();
```

Then I tried to login with a username that does not exist.

What I expected was a single JSON representation of the error. However, I always get rediverted to the login page.

Can someone advise how I can prevent Spring Security from diverting me, but instead just return the ResponseEntity in the JSON form?

Answer (score 0):

There may be more to your application than what you shared, but in the case of invalid username from the login page, your `@GetMapping` will not be invoked, nor will your `@ExceptionHandler`. This is because the Spring Security filter chain never allows your application code to be invoked prior to authentication.

In order to handle an authentication error, you will need to register an `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, where the json response would need to be written manually. For example:

```java
    public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {
            ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), exception.getMessage(), String.format("uri=%s", request.getServletPath()));
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(exceptionResponse);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

Which you can register directly with your `formLogin()` config:

```
http
    // ...
    .formLogin()
    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("pwd").permitAll()
    .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-abstractprocessingfilter) for more information on how the filter chain processes authentication requests.